# Change body style back to none

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using React to implement my application. The initial of Body CSS is nothing after render the app. However, it added the `position: relative` after rendering some scripts. Is there any way to change back to none? Is the `useEffect` in react can possible to do it?

Initial:
[image: Initial]

After rendered the script:
[image: After]

Sorry for my bad English and thank you.

Comment: What is the exact behavior that you want? I don't think you should manipulate the body style. Show us a little of your javascript code so we can understand what is being done.

Comment: I have an external script js run after rending the browser and it changed the body style to position: relative and I don't know how to change it back to none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override it by adding to your css `body{position:unset!important}`